# ExpandableListActivity with addHeader

Tags: android

Has any one added a static header to ExpandableListActivity. Please help, I want to created a header in ExpandableListActivity. 
Thanks 
Deepesh

Comment: Have a look at the link [Sticky Header and Footer to the `ListVeiw`](http://blog.maxaller.name/2010/05/attaching-a-sticky-headerfooter-to-an-android-listview/)

Comment: Hi Adil, I need this for ExpandableListActivity, I am able to do it for ListView but i want for ExpandableListActivity.

Comment: do you tried it for `ExpandableListActivity`, so what happened..? What problems are you facing..?

Comment: how to add header in ExapandableListActivity, any code link will do it Tahanks

Answer (score 1):

Just inflate the required view and add it as header:

```
View header = (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, null);
getExpandableListView().addHeaderView(header);
```